# Laravel form html with PUT method for PUT routes

Tags: php, forms, laravel, routes, put

I Have this in my routes :

```
+--------+---------------------------+--------------+---------------------------                                                                                                                ---------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                       | Name         | Action                                                                                                                                             | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+---------------------------+--------------+---------------------------                                                                                                                ---------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /                |              | postcontroller                                                                                                                                     | auth           |               |
|        | GET|HEAD login            |              | homecontroller@dologin                                                                                                                             |                |               |
|        | POST login                |              | homecontroller@dologin                                                                                                                             |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD logout           |              | homecontroller@dologout                                                                                                                            |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD post             | post.index   | postcontroller@index                                                                                                                               |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD post/create      | post.create  | postcontroller@create                                                                                                                              |                |               |
|        | POST post                 | post.store   | postcontroller@store                                                                                                                               |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD post/{post}      | post.show    | postcontroller@show                                                                                                                                |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD post/{post}/edit | post.edit    | postcontroller@edit                                                                                                                                |                |               |
|        | PUT post/{post}           | post.update  | postcontroller@update                                                                                                                              |                |               |
|        | PATCH post/{post}         |              | postcontroller@update                                                                                                                              |                |               |
|        | DELETE post/{post}        | post.destroy | postcontroller@destroy
```

Now, I want to make a form html that will use PUT method. Here is my code:

```
<form class="col-md-12" action="<?php echo URL::to('/');?>/post/<?=$post->postID?>" method="put">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Text Here" name="post"><?=$post->post?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Edit">Edit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

But i doesn't work to submit the form into post.edit.

I Have googled and i got solution that i must use

```
{{form:...etc
```

But, i want the form still can done by CSS styling.
Is there any solution guys?
Thank You

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You CAN add css clases, and any type of attributes you need to blade template, try this:

```php
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'method' => 'PUT', 'class'=>'col-md-12')) }}
.... wathever code here
{{ Form::close() }}
```

If you dont want to go the blade way you can add a hidden input. This is the form Laravel does, any way:

> Note: Since HTML forms only support POST and GET, PUT and DELETE
> methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a _method hidden field
> to your form. [(Laravel docs)](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form)

```html
<form class="col-md-12" action="<?php echo URL::to('/');?>/post/<?=$post->postID?>" method="POST">

    <!-- Rendered blade HTML form use this hidden. Dont forget to put the form method to POST -->

    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Text Here" name="post"><?=$post->post?></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Edit">Edit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Neither of these methods works in v5.4. The Forms & HTML page linked above is empty when you change the version to 5.4,

Answer (score 75):

If you are using **HTML Form element** instead **Laravel Form Builder**, you must place **`method_field`** between your
form opening tag and closing end. By doing this you may explicitly define **form method** type.

```
<form>
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
</form>
```

For `Laravel 5.1` and above

```
<form>
@method('PUT')
</form>
```

Comment: you can use `@method('PUT')` for [Laravel 5.7+](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: The @method field only really became available for Laravel 5.7. Anything under wouldn't work...

Comment: If you're curious about the need to use @method('PUT') within a Blade form, it serves the purpose of emulating/spoofing a PUT request in a web environment where forms inherently accommodate only GET and POST methods

Answer (score 57):

Just use like this somewhere inside the form

```
@method('PUT')
```

Comment: this is official for laravel 5.7

Answer (score 27):

Is very easy, you just need to use `method_field('PUT')` like this:

**Method 1**:

```
<form action="{{ route('route_name') }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

**Method 2**:

```
<form action="{{ route('route_name') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

- Update: I added new method used with latest Laravel version

**Method 3**:

```
<form action="{{ route('route_name') }}" method="post">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
</form>
```

**PUT method for PUT routes**

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

On **Laravel 8** you can do:

```html
<form action="{{ route('post.update', $post->id) }}" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
</form>
```

Using the route helper method you can start using routes names which is simply more comfortable than using complete routes. That's why i do `route('post.update', ...)`.

You will surely need the id of the resource you are going to edit hence `$post->id` in `route(..., $post->id)`.

`@method('PUT')` and `@csrf` do exactly the same as in the answers above... it just looks better.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT') // or <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{{url('/url_part_in_route').'/'.$parameter_of_update_function_of_resource_controller}}"  method="post">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">    //   or @method('put')          
....    //  remained instructions                                                                              
<form>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your view blade change to

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'postcontroller@edit', 'method' => 'PUT', 'class' = 'your class here']) }}

<div>
{{ Form::textarea('textareanamehere', 'default value here', ['placeholder' => 'your place holder here', 'class' => 'your class here']) }}
</div>

<div>
{{ Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn class here'])}}
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

actually you can use raw form like your question. but i dont recomended it. dan itulah salah satu alasan agan belajar framework, simple, dan cepat. so kenapa pake raw form kalo ada yang lebih mudah. hehe. proud to be indonesian.

reference: [Laravel Blade Form](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/124/opening-a-new-html-form)