# put method not supported in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to update a post using edit route but when I send the form and use the update function give me an error [image]

my code is

```
<form action="/posts{{$posts->id}}" method="POST">
@method('PUT')
@csrf
<label for="">title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" >
<label for="">body</label>
<textarea type="text" name="body" class="form-control">{{$post->body}}</textarea>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="edit">
```

Comment: share your routing

Comment: php artisan route:list

Comment: You need to define the route as `Route::put('posts/{id}', ...)` to get it to respond to `PUT` requests

Comment: i am using the same update route

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel form html with PUT method for PUT routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143674/laravel-form-html-with-put-method-for-put-routes)

Comment: please copy the route you use and paste it in your question

Comment: If you are using a resource controller routing you should use `action="{{ route('posts.update', [ 'post' => $posts->id ])) }}"` to be extra sure you're getting the correct route

Comment: edit your question & post your route

Comment: Is there any good reason to write a `form` tag containing `method=POST` and defining another method one line below?

Comment: @NicoHaase HTML forms don't support methods other than GET and POST and therefore frameworks like Laravel have to resort to these sort of hacks to "simulate" other methods

Comment: @apokryfos what do you mean by that? What **exactly** is simulated there, and how?

Comment: @NicoHaase check https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054241/487813 for more information. The actual override in code happens [here](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L1249) in the base symfony request (which Laravel extends)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like this

```
<form action="{{url('')}}/posts/{{$post->id}}" method="POST">
@csrf
<label for="">title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" >
<label for="">body</label>
<textarea type="text" name="body" class="form-control">{{$post->body}}</textarea>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="edit">
```

And in your route use like this

```
Route::post('/posts/{id}', ...)
```

Comment: why need `{{url('')}}` before  `/posts/{{ $post->id }}`?

Comment: @TalhaF. It's not mandatory. But it is also one kind of method to write `action method `or `href method`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a **/** in your action
`action="/posts/{{ $posts->id }}"`

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following :

```
<form action="{{ route('route.name', $post->id) }}" method="POST">
@csrf
<label for="">title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" >
<label for="">body</label>
<textarea type="text" name="body" class="form-control">{{$post->body}}</textarea>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="edit">
```

And for the route :

```
Route::post('/posts/{id}', 'Controller@function')->name('route.name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I put a hidden method that I found on laravel documents and worked fine

```
<form action="/posts/{{$post->id}}" method="POST">
@csrf
<label for="">title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" >
<label for="">body</label>
<textarea type="text" name="body" class="form-control">{{$post->body}}. 
</textarea>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="edit">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```