# Laravel error - post method not allowed on update (with @method('put))

Tags: laravel

I have a weird problem with laravel. So this error appears after I click on the edit button

```
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

And when I refresh the page it just shows me a form that should be shown. So it means the code is right... right?

Edit.Blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('categories.update', $category->slug) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('put')

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Category</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ $category->name }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="btn-updateCategory" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Update category</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This $category->slug part is not a problem I am sure.. :)

Also when I refresh page and error is gone also my controller does its job (updates category).

It also happened on other project and I thought it is my bad and since I did not know how to solve it and didn't find any mistakes in code, started that project from scratch and finished it without encountering this problem.

**EDIT**

Here is my route:list
https://prnt.sc/tvjw2i

And here is my web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function(){
   Route::resource('/posts', 'PostsController');
   Route::resource('/categories', 'CategoriesController');
});
```

***Problem solved:***
Nobody, including me, realised we are looking at the wrong form. Since error appears when I try to go on the update page and not after it, an error was on index.blade.php not on edit.blade.php.

Comment: Hey Sead, welcome to SO! Are you able to post the relevant content in your `routes/web.php`? Also - if you run `php artisan route:list` in your project root, do you see the route listed?

Comment: Also, make up your mind. :D It seems your route in `routes/web.php` for `categories.update` takes `GET` method. Your form's `method` is `POST` while another `@method` directive is set to `PUT`. Since, you're updating something, you probably want `PUT`; change route method in `web.php`. This how you send `PUT` request from view - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28144127/10625611

Comment: @Qumber hello, I have also tried PUT and the same error comes on screen this was just left from the last try :D I usually use PUT

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane there is image of my route list. I see all of them and on update is PUT|PATCH 

Also u can see here 
https://prnt.sc/tvjw2i

Answer (score 0):

It’s the issue with the route, please show us your web.php file.
If you are not registering route as resource then it should look like this

```
//route for categories update

Route::post(categories/{id}/update,’CategoriesController@update’);
```

Or if you are using resource controller

```
route::resource(‘categories’,CategoriesController’);
```

Please check this.

Comment: I've edited my question. There u can check my web.php