# Laravel8 Route(put) Not Defined

Tags: php, html, laravel

I used this Route type put in order to be able to update the profile of users:

```
Route::put('profile/{id}' , [ProfileController::class, 'updateProfile'])->name('user.profile-update');
```

However, when I link this route in my user-profile as :

```
{{route('users.profile-update', $user->id)}}
```

it's not reading it.

Comment: You need to use a  `form` with `method="post"` and need to pass hidden attribute method as `@method('PUT')`

Comment: add your form code here or check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143674/laravel-form-html-with-put-method-for-put-routes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178647/the-post-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-l)